How to Get Internal Meta Apps Approved for Instagram Messaging API Permissions?
I’m working on an internal app to centralize Instagram messaging data for reporting purposes. The app’s functionality includes logging messages from Instagram professional accounts to a database (or spreadsheet) via the Instagram Messaging API. Here’s the situation:

Purpose:


The app is read-only, meant for internal reporting (e.g., tracking incoming and outgoing messages for performance analytics).
It does not have a public-facing interface (e.g., a website or user login system).


Meta App Status:


The app has been switched to Live Mode.
Permissions requested: instagram_business_manage_messages and pages_manage_metadata.


Challenges:


Meta reviewers have rejected the app, stating that it lacks a valid use case for permissions and requesting a public-facing URL and test credentials.
My app doesn’t have a traditional web interface since its purpose is strictly internal (no third-party or public access).


Setup:


Webhooks are successfully integrated for messages and message_echoes.
Data is stored in a Google BigQuery table or spreadsheet for internal use.


Question:


How can I overcome Meta’s requirement for a public-facing URL and user credentials for an app that is strictly for internal reporting?
Are there specific steps or strategies to clarify the app’s use case during the review process?
Should I consider integrating a minimal front-end or dashboard for the sake of compliance?


Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask] - Questions should focus on a single programming-related issue - Furthermore please have a look at Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?
